# Detect Table of image using cloud vision api

Tags: image-processing, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, google-cloud-vision

I prepare some solution to detect text of the image, now I am getting bounding box of text, symbol, and language property.

Is there any way to getting table structure of documents using Google Vision API?

Comment: this question should be answered by referring to the Google Vision API's reference manual... or maybe search the web. asking this here is certainly not the right way.

Comment: I searched lot tried all ways, but i am not getting table structure, is there any other api or way to get table structure?

Comment: please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are two feature to extract text with Vision API: `Document text detection` and `Text detection` as explained in [Vision API document](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr). Both features have as response the extracted text, language and the bounding polygon of the text. Thus, you can not get the table structure directly from these two features. However, maybe you can do some workaround taking account that Vision API recognizes spaces and line break and you have the bounding polygon of each single word.